# Expected number of targets hit by 10 shooters, 2 bullets each, 20 targets

Tags: probability, expectation

> Consider a competition with 10 clay shooters. Each shooter has equal ability and they all use identical shotguns. Each shotgun is loaded with two bullets, therefore each shooter can shoot twice. One throws 20 clay targets simultaneously, each shooter picks a target at random and shoots at it once, all the shooters shooting at the same time. Then each shooter picks one of the remaining targets at random, again independently of the other shooters, and shoots at it. This ends the shooting.
>
> What is the expected number of targets to get hit?

I don't know how to answer question like this because the question doesn't give what is the probability of a shooter can hit the target.

Let's say the first shooter hit a target, then the second shooter hit $\frac{19}{20}$ of a target because I think he has a $\frac{1}{20}$ chance of shooting at the same target. The third hunter, well, if there's one target is hit so far, that's a $\frac{1}{20}$ chance, and then the third shooter hit $\frac{19}{20}$ of a target. If there are two targets get hit, then the third shooter hit $\frac{18}{20}$  of a target, but this looks pretty messy and I'm not even sure this is the correct approach. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: I think you are expected to assume perfect accuracy.The thing that makes this problem less routine is the fact that presumably each shooter uses her two shells on *different* targets.

Comment: @AndréNicolas My guess is the expected number of targets = the expected number of 1st shoot +  the expected number of 2nd shoot since the event is independent. How if we find the expected number of 1st shoot first and use the same approach to find the expected number of 2nd shoot? Is this possible?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Do you think the below answer is correct? Anyway, I'm waiting for your answer to make me more sure :)

Comment: It seems that I misinterpreted the question. I thought of the two shots as fired simultaneously.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry for my bad English. Did has edited the question for me. So, do you have a clue (an answer maybe) to solve this question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that there are $t$ targets and $s$ shooters. The first target is aimed at by the first shooter for her first shot with probability $1/t$ and hit with probability $p$ hence the first target is *not* hit by the first shot of the first shooter with probability $$q(t)=1-p/t.$$ By independence, the first target is *not* hit by the first shot of any shooter with probability $q(t)^s$. Thus, the number $T$ of targets not hit by any first shot is such that $$E(T)=t\cdot q(t)^s.$$
Assume now that $t\gt s$, hence $T\geqslant1$ almost surely. Applying once more the reasoning above, one sees that the mean number of targets not hit after two rounds of shots is $r=E(T\cdot q(T)^s)$, that is, $$r=E\left(T\cdot\left(1-\frac{p}T\right)^s\right).$$
Unfortunately, $r$ seems to depend on the full distribution of $T$, not only on its mean $E(T)$, and the hypothesis that $t=2s$ does not seem to help.

Exact computations when $t=4$ and $s=2$ yield $$r=4-4p+\tfrac12p^2+\tfrac16p^3+\tfrac1{24}p^4,$$ a formula which does not point to the possibility of huge simplification when $t=2s$ for some general $s$.

Comment: Let's analyse the first shoot only. In my opinion, using your notation, clearly this is binomial process and the probability that no one will shoot at that particular target should be $(1-1/t)^s$, therefore the expected number of target with no one shooting at them is $t(1-1/t)^s$. How come you get $p/t$?

Comment: @Venus Sorry but if you are not reading what I write, communication (and progress) will be difficult... First, we KNOW that the number of targets hit at the first shot is NOT binomial, a reason is explained in a comment to the other answer. Second we KNOW that the expected number of targets not hit at the first shot is $tq(t)^s$, this is what my answer explains. I nowhere said that the expected number of targets not hit was $p/t$ (and I nowhere studied the mean number of targets not aimed at, only the mean number of targets not hit).

Comment: The reason why I think this is binomial is from the point of view of a particular target the probability that someone will shoot at the target is $1/t$. We have $s$ independent trials, so this is binomial probability. Besides, you wrote in your answer $tq^s$, it is clearly the expected value of binomial probability. I only disagree about the $q(t)$ because I think it should be $(1-1/t)^s$. CMIIW

Comment: No, there are $s$ independent trials on the same target hence "the point of view of a particular target" is to be hit or not hit, which is *Bernoulli*, not binomial. What I wrote in my answer is $tq(t)^s$ (not $tq(t)^2$...), which happens to be the expectation of an unrelated binomial distribution, yes, as well as the expectation of an unrelated Poisson distribution as well as the expectation of a host of other unrelated distributions. That E(T)=E(Binomial) does not imply that T is binomial.

Comment: Isn't the expected number shooting at any target $p/t$ and the probability that no one will shoot at that particular target $(1-1/t)^s$?

Comment: The probability that some given shooter shoots at a given target and hits it is $p/t$. The expected number of shoots aimed at a given target is $1$. The expected number of shoots aimed at a given target and hitting it is $p$. The probability that no one will shoot at some particular target is $(1−1/t)^s$. The probability that no one will shoot at some particular target and hit it is $(1−p/t)^s$. Why do you ask?

Comment: Sorry if I asked too much question, I just try to understand the problem and your answer so that I can learn.

Comment: OK. Then reading what I actually wrote (instead of what you imagine and/or want me to write) would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is much more nuanced than I'd originally anticipated. The problem is that neither shot can be viewed as a set of independent trials, and thus not as a binomial process.

Letting $p\left(T_{i} = m\right)$ be the probability that the $i$th target is selected by $m$ shooters, and $p\left( H|m\right)$ be the probability that a target is hit if selected by $m$ shooters, then we can construct the tree $$\sum\limits_{{m_1}} {p\left( {{T_1} = {m_1}} \right)\left[ {\left. {\begin{smallmatrix}
  {p\left( {H|{m_1}} \right)}&{{n_1} = 1} \\ 
  {1 - p\left( {H|{m_1}} \right)}&{{n_1} = 0} 
\end{smallmatrix}} \right|\,\,\,\sum\limits_{{m_2}} {p\left( {{T_2} = {m_2}|T_1 = m_1} \right)} \left[ {\left. {\begin{smallmatrix}
  {p\left( {H|{m_2}} \right)}&{{n_2} = 1} \\ 
  {1 - p\left( {H|{m_2}} \right)}&{{n_2} = 0} 
\end{smallmatrix}} \right|\,\, \ldots } \right]} \right]}$$ by tracing back through the tree over all sums, which yields the probability of each tuple $\left( {{n_1},{n_2},{n_3}, \ldots ,{n_{20}}} \right)$ with $n_i = 0,1$ representing the number of hits on target $i$.

The problem is that $n_1,n_2,\ldots$ aren't IID and hence their sum isn't binomially distributed. I don't know what the conditional distribution looks like.

Let $p$ be the probability of shot success.

The expected value as a function of $p$ has the following form for some low numbers of shooters, with ${\rm number\ of\ targets = 2 \cdot number\ of\ shooters}$: $$\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
  {}&{\rm after\ first\ shot}&{\rm after\ second\ shot} \\ 
  {{n_{{\text{tgt}}}} = 2,\,\,{n_{{\text{s}}}} = 1}&p&{2p} \\ 
  {{n_{{\text{tgt}}}} = 4,\,\,{n_{{\text{s}}}} = 2}&{2p - \tfrac{1}{4}{p^2}}&{4p - \tfrac{1}{2}{p^2} - \tfrac{1}{{2 \cdot 3}}{p^3} - \tfrac{1}{{{2^3} \cdot 3}}{p^4}} \\ 
  {{n_{{\text{tgt}}}} = 6,\,\,{n_{{\text{s}}}} = 3}&{3p - \tfrac{1}{2}{p^2} + \tfrac{1}{{{2^2} \cdot {3^2}}}{p^3}}&\begin{gathered}
  6p - {p^2} - \tfrac{{11}}{{{3^2} \cdot 5}}{p^3} - \tfrac{{23}}{{{2^3} \cdot 3 \cdot {5^2}}}{p^4} + \\
  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\tfrac{{71}}{{{2^5} \cdot {3^2} \cdot {5^2}}}{p^5} + \tfrac{{17 \cdot 37}}{{{2^6} \cdot {3^4} \cdot {5^2}}}{p^6} \\ 
\end{gathered}  \\ 
  {{n_{{\text{tgt}}}} = 8,\,\,{n_{{\text{s}}}} = 4}&{4p - \tfrac{3}{4}{p^2} + \tfrac{1}{{{2^4}}}{p^3} - \tfrac{1}{{{2^9}}}{p^4}}&\begin{gathered}
  8p - \tfrac{3}{2}{p^2} - \tfrac{{17}}{{{2^3} \cdot 7}}{p^3} - \tfrac{{433}}{{{2^8} \cdot {7^2}}}{p^4} + \tfrac{{43 \cdot 307}}{{{2^7} \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot {7^3}}}{p^5} + \\
  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\tfrac{{66533}}{{{2^7} \cdot {3^2} \cdot {5^2} \cdot {7^3}}}{p^6} + \tfrac{{13 \cdot 61 \cdot 113}}{{{2^{10}} \cdot {3^2} \cdot {5^3} \cdot {7^3}}}{p^7} - \tfrac{{11 \cdot 109 \cdot 5059}}{{{2^{14}} \cdot {3^3} \cdot {5^3} \cdot {7^3}}}{p^8} \\ 
\end{gathered}
\end{array}$$ $$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{n_{{\text{tgt}}}} = 10,\,\,{n_{{\text{s}}}} = 5}&{5p - {p^2} + \tfrac{1}{{2 \cdot 5}}{p^3} - \tfrac{1}{{{2^3} \cdot {5^2}}}{p^4} + \tfrac{1}{{{2^4} \cdot {5^4}}}{p^5}} & {\hspace{140pt}}
\end{array}$$

Hopefully somebody else will take a crack at it.

Comment: I do agree with your approach but why didn't you separate the event (1st & 2nd shoot)? In my opinion, the 1st shoot we have n=10.

Comment: I used $n = 20$ because I assumed all 20 targets were shot at "at the same time". I've amended the solution. Note that the binomial process for $n_1$ in the first-shot-then-conditional-second-shot case would be $p\left( n_1\right) = B\left( n_1, \mu = \frac{p}{10}, n = 10\right)$.

Comment: Your edited version seems correct. +1. Could you make a complete answer? At least, you give me number so then I can match it using your approach.

Comment: "The first target has a 2/20 probability of being selected by the first shooter in either shot" Why? By the same reasoning, if there were only 2 targets, the first target would be selected by the first shooter in either shot with full probability?

Comment: @Did Read on; I handle the conditional case later (below the line). In the original case, since the language was used "first and second shot are both at the same time", I assumed the selection of the two was independent. Think of it as each shooter only being able to take one shot, but with a two-barreled gun that can be simultaneously aimed at two targets.)

Comment: Assume indeed that the selections of the first target and of the second target of the first shooter are independent and that the two shots are simultaneous so that every target has 1/20 chances to be selected on the second shot as well. Then the probability that the first target is selected for any of the two shots of the first shooter seems to be 1/20+(19/20)x1/20=39/400, not 2/20.

Comment: @Did I think the probability that someone will shoot at a target 
is 1/20 if we think of it from the perspective of the targets. Is that correct?

Comment: @Venus Sorry but I think your task should be to make the question clearer: how to reconcile that "first and second shot are both at the same time" and "each shot can be assumed as independent events"?

Comment: @Did: A shooter can select 2 out of N unique targets in $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  N \\ 
  2 
\end{array}} \right)$ ways. Out of these combinations, $N-1$ pairs will include a given target $T$. Thus the probability of a target being selected is $\frac{N-1}{\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  N \\ 
  2 
\end{array}} \right)}$. This yields $\frac{2}{20}$ by my calculations.

Comment: @Did Forgive my bad English, I mean the 1st shoot of each shooters occurs at the same time and the 2nd shoot of each shooters (after reloading since each of shooters has 2 bullets) also occurs at the same time which mean the 1st shoot and the 2nd shoot is two events and they are independent

Comment: @Venus: In that case, only the solution below the line is valid. I'll amend the solution.

Comment: @Venus OK, then my first comment to the OP fully apply. (Note that the targets chosen by some shooter for her first shot and for her second shot are *not* independent... but now we see what you mean.)

Comment: @Did Do you understand what I mean? If yes, would you edit my question so it will look more natural in English viewpoint? Thank you

Comment: @Venus Done. Please check this is what you have in mind.

Comment: "Thus the number of targets taken out by the first shot is a binomial process" Why? If the first target is hit, it was chosen at least once hence the chances of survival of every other target increase.

Comment: @Did: When I say "binomial process", I'm treating each target as an independent trial, not each shot.

Comment: @user46212 Are you reading carefully my comments? Anyway your reply does not answer the objection I made. (As an aside, note that an indirect proof that the number $Z$ of targets taken out by the first shot is **not** binomially distributed is that $P(Z=0)=(1-p)^{10}$ but $P(Z=10)\ne p^{10}$.)

Comment: @Did Yes! That is correct. Much better than mine. Thank you very much :) Using binomial probability, the expected number of target get hit in the 1st shoot is $20 - \frac{19^{10}}{20^{9}} \approx 8.02526$. For the 2nd shoot we have $20 - \frac{19^{10}}{20^{9}}  \approx 11.97474$ target remaining, then use the similar process like the first one. Is that correct?

Comment: @Did: You're right. There's something wrong with the calculation. I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: @Did: I've written an algorithm to compute the hit probabilities for a range of parameters.

Find it at http://jsfiddle.net/x8gdptc1/

I realize this isn't ideal, and I unfortunately don't have time to outline the algorithm in this thread. Suffice it to say that it implements the "tree" approach I mention above and that the hit distribution looks pretty Gaussian so long as the distribution doesn't saturate.

I first produced the algorithm in the symbolic domain, but it didn't avail any new insights as to a closed-form expression for the mean. At least we have an answer now. :P

Comment: You might want to use it to check the exact formula for $r$ in my answer when $t=4$ and $s=2$.

Comment: @Did: The algorithm yields $r = 1.8516$ while your formula yields $r = 3.0859$. Note that with your formula, we immediately see that $E\left[0\right] \neq 0$ in Eq. 2, which is impossible for $t > s$. It suffers from the same drawback as my first solution, which is the assumption that the probability of each target being selected and hit is independent of the probabilities of other targets being selected and hit. The reality is far more nuanced. I've put in a table of expectation values of targets hit after 1 and 2 shots for some $t = 2s$ cases.

Comment: You probably mean that the algorithm yields $r=4-1.8516=2.1484$. I corrected the theoretical formula, which, for $p=\frac12$, now yields $r=825/384=2.1484375$. I am not sure I follow the rest of your comment (E[0]?, Eq. 2? reality far more nuanced than what?). It seems the polynomial in my answer indeed gives the correct value of $r$ for every $p$ when $t=4$ and $s=2$.

Comment: @Did: Plug $p = \frac{1}{2}$ into the $n_s = 2$ 2nd shot polynomial in the table ($4p - \frac{1}{2}p^2 - \frac{1}{6}p^3 - \frac{1}{24}p^4$) and the number of expected hits comes out as $1.8516$. Your previous solution yielded $r = 3.0859$. Your new solution yields the number of targets *remaining* after two shots.